# Append to the python's dictionary key:value

Tags: python

I have a question about the dictionary in python, in the reference page: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries .

> "You can’t use lists as keys, since lists can be modified in
>   place using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like
>   append() and extend()."

But what does it mean to append the value of a python dictionary?

```
# A simple program that keep track of the line number(s) a word appeared in the novel
myDictionary = {} 
    with open('novel.txt') as book:
        lineNumber = 1
        for line in book:
            # cleaned is a helper function to clean up the line
            for word in cleaned(line).split():
                if word in myDictinoary:
                    myDictionary[word].append(lineNumber)
                else:
                    myDiciontary[word]=[lineNumber]
            lineNumber += 1
```

What exactly is going on when `myDictionary[word].append(lineNumber)` ? It seems to me a list, I want to be sure, the value of a key can be list (or in this case it is an Tuples)? **What kind of data type exactly can be used as a value? When I want the key to store multiple values.**

Comment: The citation about not being able to use lists as dictionary *keys* has nothing to do with the rest of your post, which is about modifying dictionary *values*.  You can't use mutable objects (including lists) as keys because altering a key in place will break dictionary lookup.  You can use anything you want as the value.

Comment: Yea, the reason why I ask is because I fail to see that it implicitly tell me that "any object can be used as a value". It only said what can not be used for key, now I think I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myDictionary[word].append(lineNumber)` will call the `append()` method of whatever value is stored in `myDIctionary[word]`. If that value happens to be of type `list`, then it will append a value to that `list`.

If the value stored in `myDictionary[word]` is *not* a list, or another sequence type implementing `append()`, then calling `append()` on it will be an `AttributeException`.

Comment: I see, I guess I thought the reference said the value also can not be a list, and I noticed sometimes when I forgot to type [lineNumber] and it crashes, now I think I know why.

Comment: Yes, you have to initialise the value to be a list. If you try `mydict[word] = 1; mydict[word].append(2)` this will raise an `AttributeError` for the same reason that `1.append(2)` will raise an `AttributeError` - integers don't have an `append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

*Any object* can be used as a value in a `dict`. Including a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

anything can be a value in a dictionary, hashable or not. The line in question extends a value in the dict, and not the dict itself

Comment: I think the reference page should say that :P (Anything can be a value to the dictionary). Thanks.